# How to show full file name in Ubuntu 19?

Tags: files, 19.04

I have some files on my Desktop that have longer names (but not that long actually). After about 10 letters the filename gets cutoff with a `...`. While Ubuntu 18 did show you the full name, when you clicked the file, Ubuntu 19 doesn't. Any idea what to do about this?

Comment: I looked at `gsettings list-recursively | grep ellipsis` but couldn't get things to work.