# How to show the full name of a file/folder on desktop of the Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, files, gnome-shell, directory, desktop-icons

My question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164326/how-to-show-full-file-name-in-ubuntu-19), but it is about ubuntu 20.04. Is there a way to view the full name of a file/folder on the desktop by clicking on it?

Comment: I just created a file named atoz and it is showing full name.. are you expecting in a single line?

Comment: Hello @PRATAP if the name is long, I have problem. E.g. the name of the folder "Informatica e Sistemi Tempo Reale" is visualized as "Informatica e Sistemi T..."

Comment: I just tried renaming with your value.. and it is still showing full in 3 lines.. I will add a screenshot link..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpe1X.png

Comment: @PRATAP maybe you enabled an option that in my case is disabled

Comment: no..mine is default Ubuntu 20.04..

Comment: @PRATAP I did an upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04. Also in 19.10 I had the same problem

Comment: can you try `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`

Comment: @PRATAP Done, but the situation is the same

Comment: Ok.. can we do a trail.. what if you disable this extension.. and install it locally..

Comment: @PRATAP which extension? can you tell me how to disable it?

Comment: `desktop-icons` is the extension.. follow this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1233252/739431 to make it locally.. the best is get the source of `desktop-icons` rename it.. install and enable it.. disable the default one that comes with Ubuntu 20.04 Out Of the Box!!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @PRATAP I'll try it, but I hope also to find an easier way to get what I want

Comment: the reinstall command should have done the job..thats the easier way.. but as you said it did no change.. getting the source and installing it is my immediate thought..

Comment: @PRATAP also cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04. Mine is an upgraded one, but I will immediately check on the other desktop with a fresh install.

Comment: @PRATAP Confirm: on a fresh install HDPI screen three lines at most are shown. However, it may depend on the display settings. Setting to full HD shows 2 lines. Can't get it to display only one line ;) as on my main computer (full HD, font scaling 1.20). At full HD, changing the scaling to 200% shows 3 lines.